# How does Delphi Retrieve index for IndexName property of TTable?

Tags: oracle, delphi, indexing

Here is a question about how Delphi querys the indexes from another schema in Oracle(10.2.0.4). The follow is the scenario:

There is a primary key(says myTablePK) of table "myTable", owned by A user, and my Delphi app. logons as B user who switches itself to A schema by setting CURRENT_SCHEMA=A on AFTER LOGON trigger. To identify the privilege we logon as B user and issue a query as follow , and it can successfully access the primary key of myTable:

**SQL> SELECT OWNER, INDEX_NAME FROM ALL_INDEXES; --logon as B user**

**OWNER      INDEX_NAME 

------            -------------------

A                       MYTABLEPK**

HOWEVER, I cannot get any index from IndexName property of TTable. When I clicked the property and Delphi RAD informed me to provid a acct/pwd to logon Oracle, I did and it successed. There is no any index showing up when I click the IndexName property but an empty.

Any idea?

David,
Regards

Comment: Here is the enviroment:
(1) DB: Oracle 10.2.0.4, hosted on windows 2003   (2)
RAD: Delphi 6 with BDE 5.01   (3)  Cient OS: Windows XP   (4) Oracle client: 9i (ora92)

Answer (score 0):

TTable uses the BDE and requires the connection active on TDatabase for most drivers this should display the indexes

Comment: It still does not show up the index list it "could" query. I wonder how Delphi query the indexes it could and show them in the indexName proprtty? Is it through something like 'user_indexes' view or other?